# Is there any public API to detect Lockdown Mode in iOS 16(beta 3)?

Tags: ios, swift, foundation

I was testing the lockdown mode in iOS 16 beta 3 and would like to know whether we can detect the lockdown mode status using any public API that Apple provides.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 5):

When Lockdown mode is enabled, `LDMGlobalEnabled` default is set in `NSGlobalDomain`. You can query this with

```
let isLockdownModeEnabled = (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "LDMGlobalEnabled") as? Bool) ?? false
```

Comment: can this be accessed via `window`  in javascript for use within a webapp

Comment: I don't know, but I'm pretty sure the answer is "hell no"