# Is there any way to detect LockdownMode whether it is enabled or disabled on iOS 16 using Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.ios, ios16

I have installed iOS 16(Beta 2) on iPhone XR device and iPadOS 16(beta 2) on iPad mini 5.

I have used the solution from below answer which is written in swift in below link attached. I need to simulate the swift code to Xamarin.iOS to detect Lockdown mode enabled.

[Is there any public API to detect Lockdown Mode in iOS 16(beta 3)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72956425/is-there-any-public-api-to-detect-lockdown-mode-in-ios-16beta-3#)

my code:

`bool isLockDownModeEnabled = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.ObjectIsForced("LDMGlobalEnabled");`

While LockDown mode is still on when I try to debug this it always returns false.
Required output should be "true" while LockDown mode is "ON".

Can someone help me out with this, Thank you in Advance!!

Comment: Got the answer for Xamarin.iOS to detect Lockdown mode var isLockDownEnabled = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.BoolForKey("LDMGlobalEnabled");

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer for Xamarin.iOS to detect Lockdown mode

`var isLockDownEnabled = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.BoolForKey("LDMGlobalEnabled");`

This would return correct result.